# Need Help Printing a 2D List, Rows reversed and Columns from left to Right

Tags: python-3.x

I have a function that will display numbers on a "grid". The rows need to be printed from the bottom up, and the columns to printed from left to right.
Ex.

801

000

402

[[4, 0, 8], [0, 0, 0], [2, 0, 1]]

My current code is printing out

201

000

408

[[4, 0, 8], [0, 0, 0], [2, 0, 1]]

The row 4 0 8 should print UP in the first column.

```
def display(grid):
    for rows in range(len(grid)-1, -1, -1):
        #for rows in grid[::-1]:
        
        for columns in grid[rows]:  # need to change the columns
            
            print(columns, end="")
        print("")
       
    print("\n")
    
    return
```

Comment: I have updated my answer, see if it works for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using numpy:

```
numpy.array(lst).transpose()[::-1]
```

Outputs in:

```
array([[8, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 0],
       [4, 0, 2]])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import itertools 
lst = [[8, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0], [4, 0, 2]]
lst1 = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(lst)) #unpack all sublist using iter chain
final = [[x for x in lst1[-3::-3]], [x for x in lst1[-2::-3]], [x for x in 
lst1[-1::-3]]] #  formulate the desired list using lsit comprehesion

print(final)
```

> Result

```
[[4, 0, 8], [0, 0, 0], [2, 0, 1]]
```